# Python write multiple matrix into excel using XlsxWriter

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

I need to write multiple matrices in Excel using XlsxWriter.

But I would like to specify the location of matrices in advance

Here is my code

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

CC1 = Get_Data(test1)    ## get the corresponding matrix
df = DataFrame(CC)     ## put into a dataframe format
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="sheet1")    ## write into excel 

CC2 = Get_Data(test2)    ## get the corresponding matrix
df = DataFrame(CC2)     ## put into a dataframe format
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="sheet1")    ## write into excel 
writer.save()
```

How can I specify the location of cell in which I can insert the corresponding daraframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To shift the output of the DataFrame within the worksheet, use the named arguments `startrow` and `startcol` in your call to `to_excel()`. In the following example, the output is placed with the upper left cell in E3.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from xlsxwriter.utility import xl_range

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
workbook = writer.book

df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.rand(255))
df.to_excel(
    writer, 'TEST',
    startcol=4,
    startrow=2
)
writer.close()
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It really helps.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to share my code that is able to write a matrix (list of lists) into an Excel file.

```
import xlsxwriter

table = [[a, b], [c, d], [e, f, g]] #table must be your matrix 

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('excelFile.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
col = 0

for row, data in enumerate(table):
    worksheet.write_row(row, col, data)

workbook.close()
```